# Which find() function is called when " using namespace std" added to code with while using STL set containers?

Tags: stl, namespaces, set

I've read that STL Set container has a specialized find() function which was more efficient than std::find(). My question is that which find() function would be called if I'd use `using namespace std`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::find` is a free function, `std::set::find` is a member function of set, the way to call them is different.
Refer to:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/
I will fill in the details once I reach home, but it should be obvious.

Comment: I don't see any difference between them on given examples at the website, beside "std::" part and arguments they took.

Comment: @ruynoc For a set `std::set<int> myset`, you can either call `std::find(myset.begin(), myset.end(), 3)` or `myset.find(3)`. The later is faster as it is logarithmic while the former is linear in time.

Comment: @ruynov So the compiler will know which is which

Comment: So their arguments are the way to distinguish one from another.

Comment: @ruy No, but whether it is called as a method of `myset` or not. So whether it is `myset.find` or `find`

Comment: Hi @ruynoc if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.